# Efficient way to create annulus in Healpy without nested for loop?

Tags: nested-loops, processing-efficiency, astronomy, healpy

I am trying to create an annulus of HEALPix indices using healpy by doing two disc queries.  The first corresponds to the inner radius, and the second to the outter.  I delete from the outer radius query the numpy array element where it equals a HEALPix from the inner radius, thus leaving only the annulus indices in an array to do with what I please.

```
        o_disc = hp.query_disc(nside, v_unit, o_rad)  # grabs all the indices within the o_rad input
        i_disc = hp.query_disc(nside, v_unit, i_rad)
        for j in i_disc:            # this part is for getting rid of the values inside the inner radius
            for i in o_disc:
                if j == i:
                    o_disc = np.delete(o_disc, np.where(o_disc == i)[0], 0)
                    break   # get out of this iteration 
                else:
                    continue
```

The only thing is that this takes forever to run on higher order HEALPix levels and I don't have all the time in the world.  I tried some other ways to avoid for loops, but came up empty.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to make it run faster?
Many thanks.

Comment: I believe I may have figured out the answer finally. I use the numpy function `ring = np.setxor1d(o_disc, i_disc)` which returns the values that are _only_ in o_disc, which is exactly what I want.  I ran some tests to make sure it works and it does!

Answer (score 0):

You can always just operate directly on the theta,phi coordinates of the pixels.

```
th,phi=healpy.pix2ang(nside,np.arange(healpy.nside2npix(nside))
```

then calculate calculate the angular distance from each pixel to the center of your ring, and select based on that distance, e.g. `np.where((ang<d_outer)&(ang>d_inner))[0]`.  A lazy way to do this is to convert to x,y,z, then take the arccos of the dot product, but I'm sure there's something more elegant.